# Converting nested FOR loops to PARFOR loop matlab

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, matlab

I have these nested for-loops that I would like to convert to parfor:

```
row = 1;
for i = 5 : 0.2 : 5.4
    col = 1;
    for j = 2 : 0.5 : 2.5
        matrx(row, col) = i * j;
        col = col + 1;
    end
    row = row + 1;
end
```

Does anyone any way in which this would be possible?

Answer (score 7):

I hope you're only displaying an extremely simplified version of your code, but anyways, the secret to parfor can be found by listening to Matlab numerous messages and reading the documentation. Start by learning good Matlab coding practices, and streamlining your code in such a way to fit your data into what Matlab wants in a `parfor` loop.

Things to note:

1. Parfor loops should be integers.
2. All matrices must be classified (read the documentation).
3. Container matrices should be used in nested for loops

This is one way I would do it, although it depends on your final application

```
iVal = 5 : 0.2 : 5.4;
jVal = 2 : 0.5 : 2.5;

iLen = length(iVal);
jLen = length(jVal);

matrx = zeros(iLen, jLen);

parfor i = 1:iLen
    dummy = zeros(1, jLen);
    for j = 1:jLen
        dummy(j) = iVal(i) * jVal(j);
    end
    matrx(i,:) = dummy;
end
```